# How to edit position of bones after they're assigned within the mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

I don't know how to phrase this question, I just set up the bones on a low poly model and I'm trying to adjust the position of where the joints are, the head moves too far off of it's axis as it rotates back and forth, I just want to move the joint over a bit so it moves better, but when I make a change in edit mode it changes the body in object mode. How do I just move the armature, just that on its own, so that it fits better with the actual mesh it's already assigned to without actually changing the pose?

Comment: And just like that I found the answer, to anyone else reading this reparent and change the parenting to bone relative instead of bone, instant fix

Comment: Could you post that as an answer below? Maybe elaborate a bit on the procedure, and add a few screenshots of the UI and result

Comment: I think you can also just remove the *Armature Deform* modifiers while modifying the armature.